# How to fix "double cannot be dereferenced" in Java

Tags: java

Im trying to take doubles and double arrays as parameters for my methods, but when Im calling the methods I come up with the error, "double cannot be dereferenced".

I've tried different syntaxes, such as the var.method(array[]); , var.method(array);

I've tried multiple syntaxes on my parameter sets, (double[] array), (double array[]);

```
public class Rainfall extends rainfallTest
{   

     private double total;
     private double Average;


     //total rainfall for the year
     public double totalRain(double[] rain){

     for (int index = 0; index < rain.length; index++){
         total += rain[index];
     }

     return total;

    }//end totalRain

    //calculating the monthly average
    public double monthlyAvg(double totalRain){

      Average = totalRain / 12.0;
      return Average;

    }

    //calculating the month with the most rain
    public double mostRain(double[] rain){

      double highest = rain[0];
      for (int index = 1; index < rain.length; index++){
          if (rain[index] > highest){
          highest = rain[index];
          }
      }
     return highest;    
    }

    public double leastRain(double[] rain){

      double lowest = rain[0];
      for (int index = 1; index < rain.length; index++){
         if (rain[index] < lowest){
            lowest = rain[index];
         }

      }
      return lowest;
    }
 }
```

and the testing program:

```
public class rainfallTest{



   public static void main(String[] args){

      double rain[] = {2.2, 5.2, 1.0, 10.2, 3.2, 9.2, 5.2, 0.0, 9.9, 12.2, 5.2, 2.2};
      double Average;
      double total;
      double most;
      double least;


      System.out.println("Here's the rainfall for this year");

      total.totalRain(rain);
      Average.monthlyAvg(total);
      most.mostRain(rain);
      least.leastRain(rain);

      System.out.println("The total rainfall for the year is: " + total +
                         ". the monthly average of rain is: " + Average + 
                         ". The highest rain in one month: " + most +
                         ". The lowest amount of rain in one month: " + least);

   }


}
```

Comment: You can't call methods on primitives. Construct an instance of your class and call the methods on it

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling your methods properly. First of all, you need an instance of your class:

```
Rainfall rainfall = new Rainfall();
```

Then you can call the methods on that instance, and assign the return value to your variables:

```
double total = rainfall.totalRain(rain);
double average = rainfall.monthlyAvg(total);
double most = rainfall.mostRain(rain);
double least = rainfall.leastRain(rain);
```

Also, not a huge issue, but I don't see any reason for `Rainfall` to extend `rainfallTest`.